# Pattern matching list is failing

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have the following Code:

```hs
{-
Returns a list of Strings splitted by ' '. '\\ ' is kept as ' '
-}
splitOnWhitespace :: String -> [String]
splitOnWhitespace s = concatOnBackslash $ splitOn " " s

{-
concats Strings on '\\' with a whitespace
-}
270 concatOnBackslash :: [String] -> [String]
271 concatOnBackslash [] = []
273 concatOnBackslash [x] = [x]
274 concatOnBackslash [x, xs] = case last x of
275     '\\' -> [(init x) ++ " " ++ xs]
276     _ -> [x, xs]
277 concatBackslash (x : xx : xs) = case last x of
278     '\\' -> concatOnBackslash (((init x) ++ " " ++ xx) : xs)
279     _ -> x: concatOnBackslash (xx : xs)
```

Which compiles and should return me a list of Strings splitted at a non escaped white-space.

However the following happens:

```
*Filesystem> splitOnWhitespace "a1"
["a1"]
*Filesystem> splitOnWhitespace "a1 a2"
["a1","a2"]
*Filesystem> splitOnWhitespace "a1 a2 a3"
*** Exception: src/Filesystem.hs:(271,1)-(275,24): Non-exhaustive patterns in function concatOnBackslash

*Filesystem> splitOnWhitespace "a1 a2 a3 a4"
*** Exception: src/Filesystem.hs:(271,1)-(275,24): Non-exhaustive patterns in function concatOnBackslash
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `last x` is a non-total function, it will error on non-empty lists.

Comment: The name of the last clause (`concatBackslash`) also differs fom the ones above (`concatOnBackslash`).

Comment: Enabling warnings points out the mispelling in the last line, since that would be a function without a type signature.

Comment: Thanks for that tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed correct. The first problem is that your last clause defines a function `concatBackslash`, whereas the other clauses define a function `concatOnBackslash` (with `On`). This thus means that Haskell considers this two *different* functions. You can rename these to:

```
concatOnBackslash :: [String] -> [String]
concatOnBackslash [] = []
concatOnBackslash [x] = [x]
concatOnBackslash [x, xs] = case last x of
    '\\' -> [(init x) ++ " " ++ xs]
    _ -> [x, xs]
concatOnBackslash (x : xx : xs) = case last x of
    '\\' -> concatOnBackslash (((init x) ++ " " ++ xx) : xs)
    _ -> x: concatOnBackslash (xx : xs)
```

Now the test case will work, but the function is still not very safe.

The [**`last :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:last) (and [**`init :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:init)) functions are *non-total*. For an empty list, these fail:

```
Prelude> last []
*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
Prelude> init []
*** Exception: Prelude.init: empty list
```

This thus means that `concatOnBackslash` thus will error, given the first element is empty, like:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> concatOnBackslash ["", "a"]
*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
```

You thus better use pattern matching here, like:

```
concatOnBackslash :: [String] -> [String]
concatOnBackslash [] = []
concatOnBackslash [x] = [x]
concatOnBackslash [[], xs] = ...
concatOnBackslash [x@(_:_), xs] = case last x of
    '\\' -> [(init x) ++ " " ++ xs]
    _ -> [x, xs]
concatOnBackslash ([] : xx : xs) = ...
concatOnBackslash (x@(_:_) : xx : xs) = case last x of
    '\\' -> concatOnBackslash (((init x) ++ " " ++ xx) : xs)
    _ -> x: concatOnBackslash (xx : xs)
```

Comment: But would'n it be impossible to get an empty list, when I'm splitting the String on the white-space?

Comment: @Biskit1943: no, if you for example `splitOn " " " b"`, you get `["", "b"]`, or `splitOn " " "a  b" == ["a", "", "b"]`. Perhaps it is *odd* to process such string, but nevertheless **better be safe than sorry*" :)